# Converting light to infrared

Tags: infrared-radiation

Is there a cheap / simple way of converting visible light source (ordinary white light led) into IR?

My cause is converting light source to IR signal for a universal remote control.

Comment: Why not use an IR LED? Or even a red one?

Comment: I am looking for a simple circuit to convert an already existing visible light led into an infrared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle you could convert visible to infrared radiation by shining it onto a perfectly black body. Yet, this would not help for a remote control, as these will most probably use a modulated signal and heating a black body would not be fast enough. Even if you could heat it that fast, it would for sure not cool at the required rate. Therefore your solution will be to directly use an IR LED or a simple circuit using e.g. a phototransistor to modulate an IR LED.

Comment: Yupp, thought that would be it. In the other direction, from IR to visible light there's a whole army of researchers and solutions. But I guess this time I'm on the wrong side. Ha ha.

Comment: engineer - how complex should it be to create a circuit with a phototransistor + powersource + IR led. Would it require more than a simple analog circuit, or must it have also a microcontroller ?

Comment: How about a photovoltaic driving an IR LED? (Just for fun...)